An example of a Jordan homomorphism which doesn't preserve commutativity
I need an example of a Jordan homomorphism $\phi : A \to B$  between associative algebras $A$ and $B$ over $\Bbb{C}$ which does not preserve commutativity, meaning there exist $a,b \in A$ such that $ab=ba$ but $\phi(a)\phi(b) \ne \phi(b)\phi(a)$.
Additionally, it would be great if the example could be constructed such that the $A$ and $B$ are finite-dimensional unital algebras and that the map $\phi$ is unital. But I'll be satisfied with any kind of example.
Some context:
A linear map $\phi : A \to B$ between associative algebras $A$ and $B$ is said to be a Jordan homomomorphism if $\phi(a^2) = \phi(a)^2$ for all $a \in A$. Obviously, algebra homomorphisms and antihomomomrphisms are immediate examples of such maps, but there are other examples. For instance, (taken from the comment under this question), if $A$ is a unital algebra, $p\in A$  a central idempotent and $\theta, \eta : A \to A$ are an algebra homomorphism and antihomomorphism respectively, then
\begin{equation}
A \to A, \qquad x \mapsto p \theta(x) + (1-p)\eta(x)\tag{*}
\end{equation}
is a Jordan homomorphism which is not multiplicative or antimultiplicative in general.
A map $\phi : A \to B$ between associative algebras $A$ and $B$ is said to preserve commutativity if $$ab = ba \implies \phi(a)\phi(b) = \phi(b)\phi(a)$$ for all $a,b \in A$. Clearly, all multiplicative and antimultiplicative maps preserve commutativity, as well as Jordan homomorphisms of the form (*). Furthermore, we have a more general result in this direction, which can be found in some paper by Herstein:

Let $\phi : A \to B$ be a surjective Jordan homomorphism of an algebra $A$ to a central algebra $B$. Then $\phi$ preserves commutativity.

All in all, one can see that Jordan homomorphisms preserve commutativity in many cases, and indeed all reasonable examples that I could think of indeed do so. However, I couldn't find a result claiming that this is true in general, which lead me to assume that it isn't true. I'm interested in this problem in the context of finite-dimensional algebras over $\Bbb{C}$, but on the off-chance that the claim is somehow true for this particular case, I won't stipulate this extra assumption.

See example 7.2.1  here

@Jordi This is so bizarre, I actually skimmed through the first chapter of this book after hearing Brešar himself talk about it at a lecture 5 months ago. It never occurred to me to look for an example here, though. Anyway, thank you very much, you should have absolutely posted this as an answer!

I had been looking for some references on zpd algebras recently, so I was familiar with the book and new that there were some results on commutativity preservers. Thus, I tried there and was lucky enough to find the example. I was in a rush when I wrote the comment, maybe I will make it into an answer later.
